# how to dynamically move layout?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-layout, view

I have a LinearLayout, and it have some objects that can be pressed.
To make it interesting, i move this Layout by dint of RefreshHandler

```
private void updateUI() {  
    currentInt += 5;

    LinearLayout.setPadding(0, -currentInt, 0, 0); // move, move, move

    RefreshHandler.sleep(1);  
}
```

But problem in that objects thus very much shiver!
There is more productive way? help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be accomplished much more effectively using [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html).  You may want to take a peek at the documentation on the built in [`Animation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) available.

Comment: Hmm.. If i use TranslateAnimation Layout's button can't be clicked.

Comment: And off-screen Layout part dont move.